# ctags doesn't find one function

Tags: c, ctags

I cloned [fresh gnulib](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/?id=683b6078961f10905baba598c469402ed0133425) (git://git.savannah.gnu.org/gnulib.git, Last changes: 23.03.2017) and indexed all files by `ctags` (*Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310*):

```
ctags -R gnulib
```

Surprisingly I didn't find any tag of full_write function by grep (I was particulary interested in exactly this function)

```
grep full_write tags
```

but this function is declared in a `gnulib/lib/full-write.h`

```
extern size_t full_write (int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);
```

as well as being redefined in a `gnulib/lib/full-write.c`

```
# define full_rw full_write
```

So I am really confused: why didn't `ctags` identify this particular function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To capture declaration, use --C--kinds=+p option.

```
[jet@localhost ~]$ git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/gnulib.git

Cloning into 'gnulib'...
remote: Counting objects: 174685, done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (24750/24750), done.        
remote: Total 174685 (delta 149911), reused 174636 (delta 149876)        
Receiving objects: 100% (174685/174685), 33.95 MiB | 3.97 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (149911/149911), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
[jet@localhost gnulib]$ ctags --C-kinds=+p -R
[jet@localhost gnulib]$ grep  full_write tags
full_write  lib/full-write.h    /^extern size_t full_write (int fd, const void *buf, size_t count);$/;" p
```

Comment: Where can I find full and official description of --*-kinds functionality for c language?

Comment: See the output of `ctags --list-kinds=C` in exuberant ctags or `ctags --list-kinds-full=C` in universal ctags.

Answer (score 1):

`ctags` see the declaration, but there can be many declarations. But it see no definition, because real definition looks like definition of C function named `full_rw`:
http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/full-write.c?id=683b6078961f10905baba598c469402ed0133425#n51

```
#ifdef FULL_READ
..
# define full_rw full_read
#else
...
# define full_rw full_write
#endif
size_t
full_rw (int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)
```

`ctags` have no full c preprocessing capabilities (only several preprocessing heuristics with `-I` options, documented in http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html). So `ctags` can't realize that this `full_rw` function definition defines something other, the `full_write` function. There is section of [ctags documentation](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html):

> CAVEATS
>
> Because ctags is neither a preprocessor nor a compiler, use of
>   preprocessor macros can fool ctags into either missing tags or
>   improperly generating inappropriate tags. Although ctags has been
>   designed to handle certain common cases, this is the single biggest
>   cause of reported problems. In particular, the use of preprocessor
>   constructs which alter the textual syntax of C can fool ctags. You can
>   work around many such problems by using the −I option.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't find -D option.

Comment: pgs, ctags has limitations. And there are not many places where c function name is redefined. Just don't expect ctags for doing your tasks, and find the target function in your editor (`*` in vim; search for "full_rw" in any editor).